# Program to compile files in a directory in openedge

Tags: file, compilation, openedge

Could someone help me in writing a program that has to compile all the files in the directory and report error, if any. For which my program has to get the list of all files under the folder with its full path and store it in a temp-table and then it has to loop through the temp table and compile the files.

Comment: Make it a habit to at least try something first and post what you've tried. People here want's to help but they also like effort shown!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a very rough start.

Look for more info around the COMPILE statement and the COMPILER system handle in the online help (F1).

Be aware that compiling requires you to have a developer license installed. Without it the COMPILE statement will fail.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cDir  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT "x(30)".

ASSIGN
    cDir = "c:\temp\".

INPUT FROM OS-DIR(cDir).
REPEAT:
    IMPORT cFile.

    IF cFile MATCHES "*..p" THEN DO:
        COMPILE VALUE(cDir + cFile) SAVE NO-ERROR.
        IF COMPILER:ERROR THEN DO:
            DISPLAY 
                cFile 
                COMPILER:GET-MESSAGE(1) FORMAT "x(60)" 
                WITH FRAME frame1 WIDTH 300 20 DOWN.         
        END.
    END.
END.
INPUT CLOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the comment wouldn't let me paste this much into it... using INPUT FROM OS-DIR returns all of the files and directories under a directory. You can use this information to keep going down the directory tree to find all sub directories

```
OS-DIR documentation:

Sometimes, rather than reading the contents of a file, you want to read a list of the files in a directory. You can use the OS–DIR option of the INPUT FROM statement for this purpose.

Each line read from OS–DIR contains three values: 
*The simple (base) name of the file.
*The full pathname of the file.
*A string value containing one or more attribute characters. These characters indicate the type of the file and its status.

Every file has one of the following attribute characters:
*F — Regular file or FIFO pipe
*D — Directory
*S — Special device
*X — Unknown file type

In addition, the attribute string for each file might contain one or more of the following attribute characters:

*H — Hidden file
*L — Symbolic link
*P — Pipe file

The tokens are returned in the standard ABL format that can be read by the IMPORT or SET statements.
```